# How to implement sass into ReactJS application with webpack?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I am trying to implement sass-loader in my project based on reactjs. However i am getting below error every time i build

> ERROR in ./src/modules/Login/login.scss
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> SassError: Invalid CSS after "// Imports": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var > ___CSS_LOADER_A"
> on line 1 of C:\development\basic_auth\client\src\modules\Login\login.scss
> // Imports

Below is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const env = dotenv.config().parsed;
const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
  prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
  return prev;
}, {});

module.exports = {
  watch: true,
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js'),
  devServer: {
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'build.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HWP(
        {template: path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html')}
    ),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
  ],
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  }
 }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8081",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --inline",
    "build": "webpack —-mode production"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

login.scss

```
body {
  background-color: #f2f3fa;
}

.login-content {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 100px auto 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.auth-head-icon {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #5c6bc0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #d6dee4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.registerSectionWrapper {
  background-color: #4a5ab9;
}
```

I am new to this whole setup. If anyone can help me out, i will be thankful.

Comment: Can you post the content of `login.scss` in the question?

Comment: if you could also provide the contents of package.json

Comment: @AndrewL64 i have added code of login.scss

Comment: @Dennishofken i have added code of package.json

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are missing `style-loader` from your webpack config, which I always had to include to work styles properly [sass-loader: webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/)

Answer (score 0):

if you do not use style loader you are not gonna be able to import any scss or css files inside of your app.

```
module:{
rules:[{
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"] 
     }]
}
```

in this setup, sass-loader will transform scss syntax to css. then css-loader will take over and will check for errors. if there is no error, style-loader will help importing style files and injecting styles into your application.

Comment: Thanks man. However i still not able to use syntax like "styles.registerSectionWrapper". registerSectionWrapper is a class defined in style.scss file